# How can I fix weird non-ascii character dynamic linker errors when debugging rust with clion?

Tags: debugging, rust, clion

I have this problem now that started a few weeks ago, then went away for no clear reason since it just came back.

I had been running rust stable toolchain version 1.40.0.
one of my coworkers made a code change that involved a feature from 1.43.1 so I had to upgrade.
As soon as I did, and rebuilt everything, I started getting this error when trying to debug in clion:

```
/home/smark/git/target/debug/client: relocation error: /home/smark/git/target/debug/client: symbol $�H� version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference
```

I saw a reference in the toolchain version 1.43.1 that said: "OpenSSL updated to 1.1.1g"
so I figured that might be it.
I downgraded to 1.40.0 and the debugger started working.
My coworker said I can't run versions behind everybody else, so I upgraded again.
also at this time, the rust plugin for clion got upgraded, and this time when I tried to debug it, I didn't get the error when starting to debug in clion.
So I assume it was a bug in the clion plugin that was caused by the rust toolchain update.

Everything was good, until today, when it started happening again.

Same error, I didn't update anything toolchain or clion rust plugin.

but now in addition, I also get this error when trying to debug a different binary:

```
/home/smark/git/target/debug/testreadcache: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_�.3.2' not found (required by /home/smark/git/target/debug/testreadcache)
/home/smark/git/target/debug/testreadcache: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_�.2.0' not found (required by /home/smark/git/target/debug/testreadcache)
/home/smark/git/target/debug/testreadcache: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_�.3.2' not found (required by /home/smark/git/target/debug/testreadcache)
```

Those .so files exist in the specified location, but I assume something about the mangled version number is causing it to fail.

Anyway, I rely on the debugger to do my job, and I have no idea where to begin looking to try and fix this. I clean and rebuild from scratch, I reboot, I restart the ide, I have no idea what  else to try.

the program will run from the command line, and it will run in gdb from the command line, just not in clion.

Any suggestions? Anybody ever see this before?

Comment: in a short followup, I blew away my dev vm, rebuilt it from scratch, it was working for a few weeks and just started having the same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

So if I wasn't a true rust hater before this, I am now. :-)

I think I finally figured this out, and I can't imagine I'm the only person having this problem, so if anybody else does, maybe this can help... please join me in the fight to make software better and not tolerate completely broken software like the rust tooling that exists...

I added this to the Cargo.toml in the root of my project (this only works there, it is not project specific)

```
# avoid any optimization
[profile.dev]
incremental = false
codegen-units = 1
lto = "off"
```

You'd think that debug wouldn't optimize, but it clearly does and in some cases on linux will physically butcher the binary. I'm guessing it's the lto, and I'm sure this is an llvm problem and not rust specific, but again, if I were a carpenter I wouldn't care why my hammer is broken or who designed or built it badly, I would just want my hammer to work so I could get work done and not spend endless hours fighting to make my hammer work.

Hope it helps somebody.

And thank you in advance to whatever do-gooder feels the need to edit this post so it's not so seething with anger. At least please don't remove the useful part of the answer, so that maybe somebody else won't have to suffer as I have.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error after compiling openssl and running openssl

> symbol EVP_mdc2 version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference

The solution is as follows：

1. Add a line /usr/lib in the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf file
2. Save
3. Run the ldconfig command

Reference link: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11227